# Numbering a multi-heading Excel column

Tags: excel, pivot, office365

I have an Excel sheet that needs a numbered heading (column H [in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn2RL.png)). How can I use only functions rather than VBA in this case?

Comment: Change pivot to tabular format then do a countif formular that counts the number of records in each country class

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the compact format is compulsory in my report :(

Comment: create 3 lookup columns with the values for country/class/name and then use a countif formular and and if formula to create your headers